# Can't change width and height values of a shape in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my Entity class.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Shape;
    public class Entity extends Shape{
        public var color:int;
        public function 
        Entity(xA:Number,yA:Number,widthA:Number,heightA:Number,c:int) {
            this.x=xA;
            this.y=yA;
            this.width=widthA;
            this.height=heightA;
            color=c;
            graphics.beginFill(color);
            graphics.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my main code.

```
var rectangle:Entity = new Entity(10,10,100,100,0xFF0000);
addChild(rectangle);
trace(rectangle.x+" "+rectangle.y+" "+rectangle.width+" "+rectangle.height+" "+rectangle.color);
```

And what I'm expecting is for widthA and heightA to change the width and height of the shape, but when I run the code I get this

```
10 10 0 0 16711680
```

From the trace, which indicates the x and y position are changing but not the height. Why is this?

Comment: Try removing the `this.width=widthA;` & `this.height=heightA;` lines,  and change the `drawRect` line to: `graphics.drawRect(x,y,widthA,heightA);`  Flash doesn't like it when set width and heights of empty objects (your object has no content when you set the width and height).   If that indeed solves your issue, I can write up a proper answer.   If not there a few other things I could have you try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the width and height of a display object with no graphics. Since its width and height at that point are zero, you're asking Flash to set the scale values to infinity. There's no way an empty display object can have width and height other than zero.

Try this:

```
        this.x=xA;
        this.y=yA;
        color=c;
        graphics.beginFill(color);
        graphics.drawRect(0,0,widthA,heightA); // I suspect you don't want x and y here.
        graphics.endFill();
```

The width and height will be set automatically.